# Can we return a method in generator?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, ecmascript-6

I have created a generator which yields the setTimeout with a return a value ...

```js
const wait_and_say = (a) => {
  console.log(`Wait for 4 second to get a value from Generator`);
  return setTimeout(() => {
    return a;
  }, 4000);
};

const getAnumber = function*() {
  yield wait_and_say(3.145);
  yield wait_and_say("Adams");
  yield wait_and_say("Get Cone");
  yield wait_and_say(5.12455);
};

const newNumber = getAnumber();
console.log(newNumber.next().value);
console.log(newNumber.next().value);
console.log(newNumber.next().value);
console.log(newNumber.next().value);
```

But the Output is not as desired from the above code.
The Output is undefined, undefined, undefined,
But desire output is waiting or 4 seconds to get a number.

Please Help!!!! to fix

Comment: "*yields the setTimeout with a return a value*" - no, that's not what it does, that's not how it works. Why are you trying to use generators at all here? You should use promises and `async`/`await` to *wait* for a timeout.

Comment: I'm not sure why you claim the output is undefined. It's logging the return value of each [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout#Return_value) which is a number (or a [`Timeout`](https://nodejs.org/api/timers.html#timers_class_timeout) object for Node.js [`setTimeout()`](https://nodejs.org/api/timers.html#timers_settimeout_callback_delay_args))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript is an event-driven programming language and it won't work like any other programming language where you can wait for a value to get returned.
Learn about Promises and Async/await to get know more.

```js
const wait_and_say = (a) => {
     return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
       console.log(`Wait for 4 second to get a value from      Generator`);
      setTimeout(() => {
         resolve(a)
      },4000);
   })
};

const getAnumber =  function* () {
     yield  wait_and_say(3.145);
     yield wait_and_say("Adams");
     yield wait_and_say("Get Cone");
     yield wait_and_say(5.12455);
};

(async function(){
    const newNumber = getAnumber();
    console.log(await newNumber.next().value);
    console.log(await newNumber.next().value);
    console.log(await newNumber.next().value);
    console.log(await newNumber.next().value);
})()
```

Comment: I cannot understand the concept of promise and await/async in clear text .. Can you name the resources for learning ?

Comment: @AnishGupta: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise